# Writing SpatialPointsDataFrame to Shape File gives Error rgdal::writeOGR : Non-unique field names

Tags: r, gdal, shapefile, ogr

I'm trying to write a SpatialPointsDataFrame to a Shape file, like so:

```
class(sampled_points)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

rgdal::writeOGR(obj=sampled_points, dsn=paste0(getwd(),"/Data"), layer="pixels_pakistan1", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

But I keep on getting this error

```
Error in rgdal::writeOGR(obj = sampled_points, dsn = paste(getwd(), "/Data"),  : 
  Non-unique field names
```

I can't seem to find anything on Stack Overflow that explains where this error is coming from, and I feel like I'm using the rgdal::writeOGR function correctly. Any ideas where the issue may be coming from?

Comment: What are `names(sampled_points@data)`? Names in shapefiles are limited to 10 characters; are your names unique in the first 10 characters?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue...